# WPF ComboBox Hide (Disable) DropDown Button Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I would like to know how to disable ComboBox DropDown Button Programmatically. I had seen many similar subjects but all of these have a XAML solution.

By the way, if someone know how to disable all ComboBox control design and left visible only item template it can be helpful too.

**UPDATE**

its my XAML definition

```
<ComboBox Name="lang_ComboBox" SelectionChanged="LanguageSelection_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And there is how i use it:

```
String text = "dorf";
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/4351/butchermi4.png"));
lang_ComboBox.Width = 100;
lang_ComboBox.Height = 30;
Grid sp;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol1.Width = new GridLength(30.0);
    ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridCol2.Width = new GridLength(70.0);
    sp = new Grid()
    {
        Width = 100,
        Height = 30
    };
    Image im = new Image()
    {
        Source = image,
        Width = 25,
        Height = 25
    };
    Label la = new Label() 
    { 
        Content = text
    };
    sp.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
    sp.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);
    Grid.SetColumn(im, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(la, 1);
    sp.Children.Add(la);
    sp.Children.Add(im);
    lang_ComboBox.Items.Add(sp);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Hmmm I get it now, I use wrong word. It should be "Hide" control design and still can choose from a list. My bad sorry. But i know how i can solve it with Anatoliy Nokolaev's Code. To hide control design i use:

```
ToggleButton dropDownButton = GetFirstChildOfType<ToggleButton>(lang_ComboBox);
dropDownButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Unwanted behavior is now only that i cant show combobox dropdownmenu, but I'll invoke it programmatically by add on click event and should be good.

If there is any easiest way to do this tell me :).

Comment: I can give you a more simple solution, but it will depend on the `ComboBox` template, which you arrange it? If yes, then I can give an example of it in the answer.

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev I always want to learn something new, then sure show it :)

Comment: Okay, give me time and I'll show you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable only the `ToggleButton` in `ComboBox` programmatically, you need to find this in the `ComboBox` control using `VisualTreeHelper` and assign a property `IsEnabled` to *false*, like this:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="DisableComboBoxButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox"
                  Width="100" 
                  Height="25"
                  SelectedIndex="0">

            <ComboBoxItem>Test1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox Name="AllComboBoxDisabled"
                  Width="100" 
                  Height="25"
                  IsEnabled="False"
                  SelectedIndex="0">

            <ComboBoxItem>Test1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton dropDownButton = GetFirstChildOfType<ToggleButton>(comboBox);

        dropDownButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    public static T GetFirstChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dependencyObject == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetFirstChildOfType<T>(child);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

`Output`

[image]

**`Notes`**

Always use `GetFirstChildOfType()` function only when the control will be fully loaded, otherwise it will not find it and give *null*. In this case, I put this code in the event `Window_Loaded` which says that all the controls of the Window successfully load.

**`Edit: another version`**

Not to say that this version is easier to implement, but it would be more correct and a bit easier to use.

So, we need a template for your `ComboBox`, because it allows access to elements that are within the control. Just like that, the `ToggleButton` can not be accessed from both the code and of XAML.

We create attached dependency property that will serve the current `ComboBox` another property, such as which will give access to our button Visibility.

Our property `Visibility`:

```
public static class ButtonExt
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty;

    public static void SetVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject, Visibility value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    public static Visibility GetVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Visibility)DepObject.GetValue(VisibilityProperty);
    }

    static ButtonExt()
    {
        PropertyMetadata VisibiltyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed);

        VisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Visibility",
                                                            typeof(Visibility),
                                                            typeof(ButtonExt),
                                                            VisibiltyPropertyMetadata);
    }
}
```

Setter property in ComboBox template (skip version, full version see in project in `App.xaml` file):

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                              Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, 
                                                  Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                              Visibility="{TemplateBinding PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.Visibility}" // <------ Here
                              Grid.Column="2" 
                              Focusable="False"                        
                              ClickMode="Press" />
```

Now, we are setting this property like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBaseStyle}"
          PropertiesExtension:ButtonExt.Visibility="Visible"
          Width="100"
          Height="30"
          SelectedIndex="0">

    <ComboBoxItem>Test1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Test2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Test3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

or in code-behind via Click event handlers:

```
private void HideButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ButtonExt.SetVisibility(comboBox, Visibility.Hidden);
}

private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonExt.SetVisibility(comboBox, Visibility.Visible);
}
```

Full version of example project is [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!115&authkey=!ABdG4lFRMHqtH9k&ithint=file,.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ToggleButton dropDownButton = GetFirstChildOfType<ToggleButton>(cboMedicos);
                if (dropDownButton != null)
                {
                    dropDownButton.IsEnabled = false;
                }

            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);




        public static T GetFirstChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (dependencyObject == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

                var result = (child as T) ?? GetFirstChildOfType<T>(child);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.